# trouble deleting data in an fgdb using python

Tags: python, arcpy, file-geodatabase, files

I am trying to use  delete_management to delete files in a gdb based on whether or not they are in a list. I keep getting an error with the delete_management tool that says   the file either does not exist or is not valid. I can't figure out what the problem is?

```
import arcpy, os, easygui, sys
mxd_path = easygui.enterbox("Enter directory where mxds are located:",title='Search for Data Sources')
lyr_lst = []
lyr_lst_files = []
fl_nm_lst = []
FCList = []
RList =[]
#out_loc = easygui.enterbox("Enter ouput directory for copying files:")
out_loc = r'C:\GIS\Assimilate_Mxd_Data\Assimilate_Mxd_Data_TESTING\Output Data\test_output.gdb'

#set mxd and output geodatabase directory paths, exit if not specified
if mxd_path == None or mxd_path == '':
    sys.exit()
if out_loc == None or  out_loc == '':
    sys.exit()


#generate a list of feature classes and a list of rasters already exist in
#output geodatabase
for gdb, fd, fc in arcpy.da.Walk(out_loc,datatype='FeatureClass'):
    for f in fc:
        FCList.append(f)
for gdb, fd, rasters in arcpy.da.Walk(out_loc,datatype='RasterDataset'):
    for rstr in rasters:
        RList.append(rstr)

#walk through mxds in mxd path and generate unique list of layers sourced in all
#mxd documents
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mxd_path):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if extension == ".mxd":
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
            LyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
            for item in LyrList:
                if item.supports("DATASOURCE"):
                   lyr_lst.append(item.dataSource)

lyr_lst_unique = list(set(lyr_lst))

#retrieve file names without extension from unique mxd layers lists, to compare
#with contents of output gdb
for lyr in lyr_lst_unique:
    path, file = os.path.split(lyr)
    fl_nm = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    fl_nm_lst.append(fl_nm)

#compare file names in lyr_list_unique to lists of feature classes and rasters that
#already exist in output gdb. If file names are not in FCList and RList, meaning
#they do not already exist in the gdb, copy files to output gfb
    if fl_nm not in FCList and fl_nm not in RList:
        try:
            arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(lyr,out_loc)
        except:
            print 'Input file ' + lyr + ' is not a feature class'
            try:
                arcpy.RasterToGeodatabase_conversion(lyr,out_loc)
            except:
                print 'Input file ' + lyr + ' is not a feature class or a raster'


#compare file names in fl_nm_list to lists of feature classes and rasters that
#already exist in output gdb. If files exist in gdb that are not found in mxd
#unique layers list, delete
    for gdb, fd, fc in arcpy.da.Walk(out_loc):
        for f in fc:
            if f not in fl_nm_lst:
                arcpy.Delete_management(f)
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) on f and printing the value? You can also use `arcpy.Exists()` to see if the arcpy will recognize the path as existing or not.

Comment: I did print the f values and they were as I expected.. I dont think the delete tool takes a path as input, but a layer

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may find it easier to use `easygui.diropenbox` to return the name of a directory and eliminate user mis-spellings.

Comment: If you look at the [online help for Delete_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000052000000), it shows it does take "data element" as an option.  What do you get if you print out "f" right before your last line?  Might the featureclass be in a Feature Dataset?

Comment: i guess i am getting a string list element

Comment: What if you trying putting the [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000) tool right before your `Delete_management` line?  `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(f, f + "_lyr")`

Comment: no same error as before

Answer (score 1):

f variable only contains the name of the featureclass.

You could set the environment workspace variable

```
arcpy.env.workspace = out_loc # "C:/data/base.gdb"
```

Or you could join the path as the [ESRI help suggest](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000):

> Names in the lists include only the base name; no path components are
>   included. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or
>   directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

In your case replace the last line with:

```
arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(gdb, fc))
```

Please note that I'm sure about witch is better if you have featureclass in dataset.